# Kill turtle which causes runtime error

Tags: runtime-error, netlogo

I'm curious as to whether there is a way of reporting the turtle which causes a runtime error?

I have a model which includes many agents and will run fine for hours, however sometimes a runtime error will occur. I have tried a few different things to fix it but always seems like an error occurs to the point I can't spare the time to fix it due to deadlines.

As the occurrence is so rare the easiest solution is to just write in the command center ask turtle X [die] after which I click GO and the problem is 'fixed'.

However I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to kill the turtle producing the error automatically every time a runtime error occurred to save me entering this manually.

Comment: globals [x]
to test
  ask turtle 0 [carefully [print 1 / x] [die]]
end

Comment: Something else you might try for your debugging is to start using a random seed. That way, each run will be identical.You then run it until it crashes, look at what tick it is up to and then run it again but stop just before that tick and look to see if there's something unusual